# Send mail with System.Net.Mail

Tags: .net, email, system.net.mail

I have a requirement to build a .net 3.5 webpage for a client which will automatically email users, taking addresses from a customer database.

I can get this working fine for internal mail using the system.net.mail, but can anyone tell me if this is suitable if the clients email service is through a 3rd party, rather than having their own exchange server?

I heard the best way to go is using his suppliers smtp relay service, can anyone point me in the direction of any examples of this, or even an idea of whats involved?

thanks

DD

Comment: the namespace System.Net.Mail and its class does not require Exchange.
It only require a SMTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Net.Mail does this for you. Make sure you use the System.Net.Credentials to provide both the proxy authentication and the SMTP server authentication and all should work fine. 
for more information look up the [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx).